# see what code gets executed in realtime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm running an application from **Visual Studio** 2012 in **debug mode**,

I would like to see what code gets executed in realtime, which would be equivalent to doing

```
Console.WriteLine(" command.do ... etc. ");
```

after every single line

is it possible to see what code gets executed, in real time ?

Comment: If I were _you_, I'd just roundhouse kick my PC until it does just that.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the first line and press F5... magic!

Comment: Or press F11. Will automagically break on the first line.

Comment: Chuck Norris can sort lists in linear time.  He uses a variant of QuickSort called KickSort.  He can also factor huge integers by kicking them apart.

Comment: @Adriano I'm running the application from Visual Studio, and I'm in debug mode, there's no remote involved, I just a realtime log

Comment: Can't you use the plain old breakpoint?

Comment: So what's wrong with IntelliTrace, step by step debug or plain old logs?

Comment: @Adriano the app has lots of threads and uses many libraries, and the problem I'm trying to get to happens when I'm running about 200 bots against it, which is about as many threads + background stuff, plus when it happens it goes to 100% cpu

Comment: Such heavy logging (assuming there is a way to do exactly what you want) will change everything (and it'll consumes more CPU time than your bug). Better to refine log to small relevant points, to use another tool (for debugging thread issues) or IntelliTrace to collect "side data".

Comment: @SidharthMudgal I want to  see what code gets executed when the application hangs on 100 % CPU

Comment: @Adriano I think InterlliTrace might be what I'm looking for, cuz all I want is to know what happened (code executed) at a certain moment, will read more about it

Comment: @ChuckNorris home made solution I used once for something like this: download MSE (Microsoft Stack Explorer) source code. Use a performance counter to monitor CPU and take few snapshots of threads stack when CPU > 95%. It won't affect normal execution and you may (after few tries) get more or less the direction where you should investigate.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes, technically it is feasible to accomplish this.

No, you will not find tools to do that (I can't be 100% sure on what doesn't exist of course).

---

This can be done using profiling API provided by .NET framework. Some profilers even advertise line-by-line tracing, but this only means that they will measure timing on every single line instead of using some shortcuts to lower performance hit.

You should however try to explain what you ultimately want to accomplish, rather than trying to forcing yourself down the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at a tool like JetBrains. It has a 10-day free trial and it integrates into Visual Studio very nicely.

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

This doesn't do exactly what you're asking for. But I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging real time, one should not delay the program. This can be done using external hardware, like a logic analyser, which doesn't come cheap.

Instead of tracing the execution of every line, it is better just to trace the execution of some important lines. That trace must be EXTREMELY fast. Visual Studio's trace is way too slow and blocks a second thread calling Trace, a big No No in real time debugging.

Luckily, it is easy to write your own memory trace, which causes only microseconds delay and is non blocking:

```
const int maxMessages = 0x100;
const int indexMask = maxMessages-1;
string[] messages = new string[maxMessages];
int messagesIndex = -1;

public void Trace(string message) {
  int thisIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref messagesIndex) & indexMask;
  messages[thisIndex] = message;
}
```

A more detailed description for this approach which also collects thread and timing information and outputs the trace nicely is at:
CodeProject: Debugging multithreaded code in real time [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792532/Debugging-multithreaded-code-in-real-time)